# Pdftron Webviewer custom form field

Tags: javascript, pdftron

How can I create a custom form field?

Goals I want to accomplish

- Create Button
- Add custom logic on button click

There are SignatureWidgetAnnotation, CheckButtonWidgetAnnotation, but how can I control click event?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

First you create an AfterAction entry on the Widget.

```
Obj aa_dict = mywidget.GetSDFObj().PutDict("AA);
```

Then you create your action, and add to the "U" key for click. For instance, below will add a Javascript entry.

```
Obj alert_js = doc.CreateIndirectDict();
alert_js.PutName("S", "JavaScript");
alert_js.PutString("JS", "app.alert(' Hello World! ');");

// Associate this JS action with 'On Mouse Up' event.
aa_dict.Put("U", alert_js);
```

See Table 194 [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for full list of actions to hook into.